# Bootstrap and topcoat styles overlap, mobile slide menu background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I want to use two css styles bootstrap and topcoat. I use the angular slide menu feature (ng-mobile-menu). When I add the bootstrap cdn. it overrides the topcoat menu as the result the background color of the slide menu become shorter just cover the menu list: http://www.elmandato.pl but it should be http://www.shoppinpal.github.io/ng-mobile-menu/demo/#/skinny. That should I add to (change order of link rel doesn't matter):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="topcoat/css/topcoat-mobile-dark.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0./css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ng-mobile-menu.min.css"/>
<style>
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
}

#menubutton {
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* vertically center button text */
  line-height: 3rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #454545;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid #a5a8a8;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is overriding topcoat because you've placed the link to it below topcoat. CSS cascades from the top down, meaning bootstrap overrides, topcoat, and ng-mobile-menu.min.css overrides bootstrap and topcoat. Try putting bootstrap above topcoat, then use developer tool to see what the selectors are for the classes / ID's and overwrite if needed